# Illegal division by zero

Tags: perl, divide-by-zero

```
@xyVal = (4,4,6,6,10,12,18,22,24,28,30);
@yVal = (176,178,180,184,192,202,210,218,224,232,238);

@xxVal = (9,9,9,9,9 ,11,13,15,17,19,19);
@xVal = (168,166,164,162,158,150,142,134,122,116,110);

for ($i = 0; $i <  scalar(@xVal); $i++){
    for ($i = 0; @xyVal[$i] < @xxVal[$i]; $i++){
        @yNewVal = @yVal[$i-1] + (@yVal[$i] - @yVal[$i-1])*(@xxVal[$i] - @xyVal[$i-1])/(@xyVal[$i] - @xyVal[$i-1]);
    }
}
print @yNewVal;
```

I understand why its giving me the error `Illegal division by zero` about line 9 (the @yNewVal = ...)

I want the array to have 0 in it if there is a division between zeros. What am I doing wrong? So, how can I avoid that my application crashes when there is a division by zero?

Comment: A small note: using the @ sigil when accessing a single element works, but it isn't doing exactly what you think it is.  When you use @, you're taking a slice: i.e., returning an array of one element.  If you only want to access a single element in the array, usually you should use the `$` sigil.  If you enable `strict` and `warnings`, you'll see warnings like `Scalar value @xyVal[$i] better written as $xyVal[$i] at - line 8.` that let you know this. :)

Comment: just add `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of your script to get these helpful hints in the future! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your divisor on that line is `@xyVal[$i] - @xyVal[$i-1]`, so any case where you have two identical adjacent values in `@xyVAl` (e.g. `4,4`) will result in a 0, and thus a divide-by-zero error.

Comment: oh is that right..  interesting. even thought its i and i-1... how am i to subtract it then?

Comment: Um, in this case it's a matter of program logic: you're dividing by zero because you're putting zero in the denominator.  I think you meant something other than xyVal[] - xyVal[] .... perhaps xyval - xxVal?

Comment: `$i` is your indexer, so in plain English you're taking one value in the array and subtracting from it the previous value. If both values are the same (e.g. `4, 4`) the result is 0, and hence the divide-by-zero error. `sharpner`'s answer is probably what you need to use.

Comment: Awesome - I don't think I've ever answered a Perl question before. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could say:

```
@yNewVal = ($_ = @xyVal[$i] - @xyVal[$i-1]) == 0 ? 0 : @yVal[$i-1] + (@yVal[$i] - @yVal[$i-1])*(@xxVal[$i] - @xyVal[$i-1])/$_;
```

Answer (score 1):

well if i understand you correctly:

```
if (@xyVal[$i] == @xyVal[$i-1]) 
@yNewVal = 0; 
else 
@yNewVal = @yVal[$i-1] + (@yVal[$i] - @yVal[$i-1])*(@xxVal[$i] - @xyVal[$i-1])/(@xyVal[$i] - @xyVal[$i-1]);
```

Comment: this causes my program to give me non-stop print of `0`

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a try/catch using `eval` and conditional operators.

```
eval {
    @yNewVal = @yVal[$i-1] + (@yVal[$i] - @yVal[$i-1])*(@xxVal[$i] - @xyVal[$i-1])/(@xyVal[$i] - @xyVal[$i-1]);
    1;
} or do {
    @yNewVal = (0);
}; 
print @yNewVal;
```

Though, your phrase is returning a scalar value and putting it into an array variable. So you may want to re-factor that.

Comment: this gives me 183 repeated the entire time. :/